# Wordpress issue trying to assign a parent level and a child level term to a variable for each post

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get a parent level custom taxonomy category name to output to an h6 tag, and I also need to get the child category name and output it in an h5 tag. I thought it would be simple by just accessing the index of the get_terms array, but the return doesn't seem to be consistent. Any suggestions would be greatly apprececiated. Is there a more efficient way to get a parent category, and a child category for a post?

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'news-categories' );   
if(count($terms) > 1) { 
     echo '<h5><i class="fas fa-tag"></i> ' . $terms[0]->name . '</h5>'; 
     echo '<h6><i class="fas fa-tag"></i> ' . $terms[1]->name . '</h6>'; 
}
```

Here's a var_dump of the output of terms

```html
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Term)#2985 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(45)
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "Project Spotlight"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(17) "project-spotlight"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(45)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(15) "news-categories"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(87)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(WP_Term)#2965 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(47)
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "Workforce Preparedness"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(22) "workforce-preparedness"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(47)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(15) "news-categories"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(45)
    ["count"]=>
    int(37)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
}
```

Just as a note "Project Spotlight" should always show as the parent and "Workforce Preparedness" should return as the child, however, it's inconsistent on some posts.

Comment: Why do you have the `foreach`? It doesn't look like you are using it anywhere. Also, can you edit the question to include a `var_dump` of what you're getting from `$terms`?

Comment: Thank you for helping I've updated the comment with the var_dump. I'm using the foreach later on in the template. It wasn't pertinent for the question. I've removed that